# Make denormalized JSON hierarchical

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working with denormalized JSON structures but I need nested JSON to iterate over them in multiple levels on the client side. I'm stumped how to do this elegantly.

Can you think how to easily transform JSON of the form

```
[{ category: xyz, attribute: 1},{ category: xyz, attribute: 2}]
```

into a hierarchical format:

```
[{category: xyz, attributes: [1,2]}] ?
```

Much much thanks for any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this all the time, though usually on the server side. The code looks something like this:

```
function normalize(key, outputKey, data)
{
    var results = [];
    var record;

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        if(!record || record[key] != data[i][key])
        {
           record = {};
           record[outputKey] = [];
           record[key] = data[i][key];
           results.push(record);
        }

        delete data[i][key];
        record[outputKey].push(data[i]);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
[
  {
    "category": "xyz",
    "values": [
      { "attribute": 1 },
      { "attribute": 2 }
    ]
  }
]
```

Note that your example output is messed up. You might want to decide if you're trying to group objects or values of an array. The latter is even easier.

**EDIT:** Of course, you were looking for the boring answer. Here you go:

```
function collapse(key, attr, data)
{
    var results = [];
    var record;

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        if(!record || record[key] != data[i][key])
        {
           record = data[i];
           record[attr] = [data[i][attr]];
           results.push(record);
        }
        else
        {
            record[attr].push(data[i][attr]);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

If you call it like this:

```
var data = [{ category: 'xyz', attribute: 1},{ category: 'xyz', attribute: 2}];
collapse('category', 'attribute', data);
```

You'll get this output:

```
[{"category":"xyz","attribute":[1,2]}]
```

Comment: Your answers are pretty clever, but you modify the original array. You should have pointed that out.

Comment: Thank you - you are all incredibly awesome.

Comment: I knew I forgot something. Thanks for pointing it out Hoffmann! Obviously you'll need to copy the object if you don't want to destroy the original objects.

Comment: Copying would be pretty slow if the json is big. You might just do it like I did, I do not modify the original array in my answer.

Comment: If it's a shallow copy (which is all that's really needed) and you do it only at the points where a new result object is created, it should be pretty fast. My current solution is O(n). If you did a copy, it would be O(n + r) where r is the number of objects in the results. This would be a worst case performance of 2n, best case n + 1.

Comment: Just realized the fastest way to do the clone. If you perform a jQuery.extend() on the object, all the original values will shine through yet you can override the ones you care about. (Like changing attribute to an array.)

Comment: Yes I myself use $.extend() all the time and I guess in this case a shallow copy is indeed enough. You have to be careful when you modify function parameters, that generates all kinds of hairy and hard to debug bugs. For some time now I have been just $.extend(true, ...) many of my object/arrays function inputs.

Comment: Props to Hoffman, the object modification is causing heinous bugs all over my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
function reorder(arr) {
    var heir = {};
    arr.forEach(function(i){
        for (var j in i) {
            if (heir[j]) {
                if (heir[j].indexOf(i[j]) == -1) {
                    heir[j].push(i[j]);
                }
            } else {
                heir[j] = [i[j]];
            }
        }
    });
    for (var i in heir) {
        if (heir[i].length == 1) {
            heir[i] = heir[i][0];
        }
    }
    return heir;
}
```

This won't perfectly conform to your example, but pretty close:

```
{ category: 'xyz', attribute: [ 1, 2 ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

When I have to do stuff like this I usually build external arrays with metadata to improve code readability. So don't do it like this if your JSON is huge.

```
function normalize(json) {
    var categories= [];
    var norm= [];
    for (var i=0; i < json.length; i++) {
         if (categories.indexOf(json[i].category) !== -1) {
              categories.push(json[i].category);
         }
    }
    for (var i=0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        norm.push({ category: categories[i]; attributes: []});
    }
    for (var i=0; i < json.length; i++) {
        norm[categories.indexOf(json[i].category)].attributes.push(json[i].attribute);
    }
    return norm;
}
```

My answer is O(n*log(m) + n + n*m), where n is the length of the outermost json and m is the number of categories, but the n*log(m) and n*m are the indexOf part and it is done in native code by the browser. I'm too lazy to do proper big O comparison with the other answers, but this is clearly slower.